# Storage Extension: Remove method not invoked while unpublishing

Tags: 2013-sp1, content-delivery, deployer, storage-extensions

We are using SDL Tridion 2013 SP1 and extending the storage using Storage Extension feature. Storage Binding file is as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<StorageDAOBundles>
  <StorageDAOBundle type="persistence">
    <StorageDAO typeMapping="ComponentPresentation" 
                class="com.tridion.storage.extension.dao.JPASearchComponentPresentationDAO"/>
  </StorageDAOBundle>
</StorageDAOBundles>
```

Storage Binding file's info is added to `cd_storage_conf.xml`.

While the `create` method is rightly invoked while publishing the Component Presentation, `remove` method is not getting invokved whenever Component Presentation is unpublished.

What is more to be done to have `remove` method invoked while unpublishing Component Presentation?

Answer (score -1):

For query specific to your custom development of storage extension.

I would recommend to include more debug log information to see where your transaction action stands when unpublishing also include more logs in your JPASearchDAOFactory, also check which remove method it's invoking

```
public class JPASearchComponentPresentationDAO extends JPAComponentPresentationDAO implements ComponentPresentationDAO
{
    @Override
    public void remove(ComponentPresentation itemToRemove, ComponentPresentationTypeEnum componentPresentationType) throws StorageException
    {
        super.remove(itemToRemove, componentPresentationType);
        LOG.debug("Removal method 1");

    }

    @Override
    public void remove(int publicationId, int componentId, int componentTemplateId, ComponentPresentationTypeEnum componentPresentationType) throws StorageException
    {
        super.remove(publicationId, componentId, componentTemplateId, componentPresentationType);
        LOG.debug("Removal method 2");
    }
}
```

Comment: "remove" method in the extended class is not getting invoked. Deployer executes the default unpublishing from broker DB correctly without executing the extension part.